# How do I generate a flat array of indexes from a multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have the following array from PHP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ContractExhibitsData] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [exhibit_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ContractExhibitsData] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 98
                                    [exhibit_id] => 2
                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ContractExhibitsData] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 99
                                                    [exhibit_id] => 2
                                                    [parent_id] => 98
                                                )

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ContractExhibitsData] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 100
                                                    [exhibit_id] => 2
                                                    [parent_id] => 98
                                                )

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

It is essentially a tree array, consisting of nodes with child nodes with more data. I want to iterate over this array using a recursive function to generate an array like this:

```
$return = Array
(
    [2] => '1.',
    [98] => '1.1.',
    [99] => '1.1.1.',
    [100] => '1.1.2.'
);
```

And so forth. Basically, it will be a bunch of Key-Value pairs where the array key is the 'id' of the element in `ContractExhibitsData` and the value is the numerical index.

I have the following function that I have been tinkering with, but it isn't getting me quite where I need to be.

```
private function getIndexes($data, $prefix = null) {

    $indexes = array();
    $count   = 0;

    if ($prefix) {
        $prefix = $prefix . '.';
    }

    if (!empty($data['children'])) {
        foreach($data['children'] as $child) {
            $count++;

            $indexes[$child['ContractExhibitsData']['id']] = $prefix.$count;

            if (is_array($child['children']) && !empty($child['children'])) {
                $subIndex = $this->getIndexes($child, $prefix.$count);
                return $subIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    return $indexes;

}
```

Comment: not answering your question but maybe interesting for you and something you might switch to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: How is that supposed to help me? I cannot change the way I am receiving this data, nor the way it is stored.

Comment: As is said, not answering your question, just something that you might be able and want to switch to.
Also: What is the outcome of your function? what is the problem with your function? Consider providing a plunkr/ideone or something like that. http://ideone.com/

Comment: you return a subindex in the foreach loop thus, breaking your foreach loop and therefore never ever looping over your full array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! See the working version [here](http://ideone.com/ZCXENj).

```
<?php

function getIndexes($data, $prefix = '') {

    $indexes = array();
    $count   = 1;

    if (!empty($prefix)) {
        $prefix = $prefix . '.';
    }

    foreach ($data as $dataItem) {
        $item   = $dataItem['ContractExhibitsData'];
        $index  = $prefix.$count;

        $indexes[$item['id']] = $index;

        if(!empty($dataItem['children'])) {
            $indexes = array_merge_recursive($indexes,getIndexes($dataItem['children'],$index));
        }
        $count++;
    }

    return $indexes;

}

$yourArray = array
(
    0 => array (
        'ContractExhibitsData' => array
        (
            'id' => 2,
            'exhibit_id' => 2,
            'parent_id' => null
        ),
        'children' => array
        (
            0 => array
            (
                'ContractExhibitsData' => array
                (
                    'id' => 98,
                    'exhibit_id' => 2,
                    'parent_id' => 2
                ),
                'children' => array
                (
                    0 => array
                    (
                        'ContractExhibitsData' => array
                        (
                            'id' => 99,
                            'exhibit_id' => 2,
                            'parent_id' => 98
                        ),
                        'children' => array()

                    ),
                    1 => array
                    (
                        'ContractExhibitsData' => array
                        (
                            'id' => 100,
                            'exhibit_id' => 2,
                            'parent_id' => 98
                        ),
                        'children' => array ()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$result = getIndexes($yourArray);
var_dump($result);
```

One of your problems was that you had a return in your loop, thus breaking your loop. Also, you added null as a string since that was the default setting of your $prefix. You alos never iterated over the initial array but always just the children.

Comment: Cheers :) Works perfect